# Different indentations of same level in ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, indentation

I am  writing a paper for university and I need to do it according to style guides. Everything looks peachy, except for the ToC.

This is how it comes out for me:
[image]

The word "appendix" shouldn't overlap with the section name, but also the non-appendix subsections cannot be further to the right than they are now. That's why I cannot use

```
\renewcommand\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{3em}}
```

Following is the code I have in my *.cls file which might have some influence in current formatting.

```
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
}

\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty\@secpenalty
        \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}
        \begingroup
            \vspace{1.5mm}
            \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
            \leavevmode {
            \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
            \hskip -\leftskip
            \MakeUppercase{#1}}\nobreak\ %
            \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
            \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
        \endgroup
    \fi
}

\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection} appendix.}
}
```

The ToC in the image was generated with following statements:

```
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\section{Appendices}
\appendix
\subsection{Awesome appendix}
\subsection{Not so awesome appendix}
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package to change the formatting for subsection entries just before the appendices; here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty\@secpenalty
        \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}
        \begingroup
            \vspace{1.5mm}
            \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
            \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
            \leavevmode {
            \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
            \hskip -\leftskip
            \MakeUppercase{#1}}\nobreak\ %
            \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
            \hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
        \endgroup
    \fi
}

\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection} appendix.}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\section{Appendices}
\appendix

\titlecontents{subsection}
  [7.5em]{}
  {\contentslabel{6em}}
  {\hspace*{-6em}}
  {\titlerule*[0.6pc]{.}\contentspage}

\subsection{Awesome appendix}
\subsection{Not so awesome appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your actual document, all you need to do is to load the package and

```
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [7.5em]{}
  {\contentslabel{6em}}
  {\hspace*{-6em}}
  {\titlerule*[0.6pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

ust before the subsections corresponding to the appendices.

Comment: You are a life saver. This is the most correct and cleanest looking answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

use a modified definiton of `\l@subsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\section{Appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand\string\l@subsection{\string\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{6em}}}
\appendix
\renewcommand\thesubsection{appendix~\arabic{subsection}}
\subsection{Awesome appendix}
\subsection{Not so awesome appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]